# Choosing specified cells in a column range and show in dependent excel drop-down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, list, dropdownlist

I want to create a data table (*Table3*) that col [*Member*] will fill members name by a drop-down list from the *Table1*[*Mem No*] and I want to fill the [*book*] column of *Table3* from the column *Table2*[*books*] of but I have the problem how to create a drop-down list in column [*books*] that just show the Books that related in members in *Table3*[*Member*].

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want a cascading dropdown list

Comment: thanks. But I want to have a dropdown list that show some data from a column that meet one or more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome @M.Rafi Biglari

I understand you want a dynamic dropdown list for data validation, i.e. if member G3 is Mem1, then the dropdown in H3 must only allow you to choose Book1, book2 or book3.

To do this, **NB** put your cursor in H3, then define a named range (Data > Define name) and call it `varlist`. In *refers to*, put the following formula

```
=INDEX($E$3:$E$15,MATCH(G3,$D$3:$D$15,0)):INDEX($E$3:$E$15,MATCH(G3,$D$3:$D$15,0)+COUNTIF($D$3:$D$15,G3)-1)
```

Now, select you data validation as list in cell H3, and type `=varlist` in the source.